How to define infinite sums in nonstandard analysis for general vector spaces?
I'm studying nonstandard analysis and I came across the concept of infinite sums in this framework. I understand that in standard analysis, infinite sums are typically defined through the concept of convergence. I've read that in nonstandard analysis, it's possible to define infinite sums without explicitly using convergence.
My question is whether this concept of an infinite sum can be defined for elements of a general vector space, not just real numbers.
Specifically, I'm looking at the sum of an internal sequence $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^\omega$
,where $\omega$ is an infinite natural number and $v_j$ is a real number. The notation used is:
$\sum_{j=1}^\omega v_j.$
Is it possible to define such an infinite sum if $\{v_j\}$
are elements of a general vector space, rather than just real numbers? If so, how is this definition extended to general vector spaces?
Any detailed explanation or reference to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It should be the same as the definition of the ordinary sum: by induction. Yes? By the way, I would really hesitate to call this an "infinite sum." It is a nonstandard sum.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you for your comment. I am not sure about the meaning of your comment because I am new to nonstandard analysis. But, I want a definition of nonstandard sums that is "compatible" with ordinary finite sums.

Let $V^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of all functions $\mathbb N \to V$ for $V$ a vector space. Then there is a sum function $S : \mathbb N\times V^{\mathbb N} \to V$ defined by $$S(N, f) = \sum_{n=0}^Nf(n).$$ Take the nonstandard extension ${}^*S$ of this and apply it to an infinite hypernatural. Like Qiaochu Yuan says this probably shouldn't be called an "infinite sum", it's just a "sum up to a nonstandard hypernatural".

If $V$ is a vector space and $a_i\in V$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ are vectors, we can define finite sums $s_n=\sum_1^n a_i$.  These define a sequence $s:\mathbb N \to V$.  The star transform provides an extended sequence (still denoted $s$) which is a map $s:{}^\ast\hskip-1pt\mathbb N\to {}^\ast\! V$.  Then the "infinite sums" you are looking for are the values of $s_n$ at infinite integers $n=H$.  (In some contexts it is preferable to use the term "unlimited" in place of "infinite".) The series $\sum a_i$ is summable (to $L$) if and only if all such $s_H^{\phantom{I}}$ are infinitely close to $L$.
